# Slow query operation with recursive CTE

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a query  in which I use a recursive CTE. Unfortunately, when I'm extending the entry dates, the time increases significantly.

Would anyone be able to help me how to change the code to make the query work more efficiently?
The problem seems to be in CTE4.

I am surprised by the slow operation of the query, because the result is generally a simple excel action. Like this:

Performance = x_prev * (1 + x)

```
DECLARE       @BegOfPeriod DATE = '20100101'
             ,@EndOfPeriod DATE = '20191231'
             ,@clientID INT = 200010;

WITH
CTE AS
(
SELECT  d.Date
        ,1+COALESCE(twr.day_diff_pct,0) as DayPct_plus1
FROM Days d
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DailyTWR] TWR ON   d.Date=twr.date AND Clientid=@clientID
WHERE d.Date between @BegOfPeriod and @EndOfPeriod  AND d.Date>=(SELECT min(date) FROM DailyTWR WHERE ClientiD=@clientID)
),


CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *
        ,LAG(DayPct_plus1,1,1) OVER (order BY date) as DayPct_plus1_Prev
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by date) as rownum
FROM cte
),


CTE3 AS
(
SELECT  *
        ,c2.DayPct_plus1*c2.DayPct_plus1_Prev Performance
FROM CTE2 c2
),


CTE4 AS
(
SELECT  c3.date,c3.DayPct_plus1,c3.DayPct_plus1_prev,c3.rownum,c3.Performance
FROM CTE3 c3
WHERE rownum=1


union all

SELECT  c3.date,c3.DayPct_plus1,c3.DayPct_plus1_prev,c3.rownum
        ,c3.DayPct_plus1*c4.Performance as Performance
FROM CTE4 c4
JOIN CTE3 c3 ON c3.rownum=c4.rownum+1
)


SELECT c4.Date,c4.Performance
FROM CTE4 c4
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: It may help to populate CTE3 in a temporary table first. Do note that recursive CTEs aren't known for their good performance in SQL Server.

Comment: can you share the ddl and the dml and the expected results